# setImageResource Vs setDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout

When it comes android development and performance, if you have imageview then which one would be faster or better (is there a difference anyways!): setImageResource and setDrawable
Iknow one takes ID and the other one takes drawable. But I will be getting the drwable from ID anyways.
Which one do you think is better?

Or should I avoid using imageview alltogether and use load/draw bitmap?
too many selections is confusing
Thanks for the comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222549/difference-of-setting-an-image-from-resource-to-drawables

Answer (score 74, accepted):

They are different. From [Android documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29).

setImageResource:
This does Bitmap reading and decoding **on the UI thread**, which can cause a latency hiccup.

If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Comment: In my GridView adapter I used setImageResource and it lagged on scrolling. When I changed calls to setImageBitmap, GridView began to scroll smoothly. Execution time of these 2 methods is obviously different. However, it makes no difference what to use, if developer works with static views (which are not moved).

Comment: Accepted the new answer :)

Comment: `setImageDrawable` is also too slow

Comment: @konopko could you elaborate please? Is setImageDrawable demonstrably slower as compared to setImageResource?

Answer (score 2):

I think `setImageDrawable` is better suited for memory intensive operations - like scrolling a RecyclerView, getting bitmap from memcache.  But for something simpler, `setImageResource` is the better API nowadays.

Comment: What do you mean by "setImageResource is the better API nowadays"? They have improved how it retrieves/caches the drawable?

Comment: @Farid It is better because it is a simpler API