# Difference of setting an Image from Resource to Drawables?

Tags: android

Example of this is for setImageResource vs. setImageDrawable
same goes for a Background?

What is the preferred choice then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774705/setimageresource-vs-setdrawable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) `setImageResource` does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. So your question would be better if you'd ask in which cases `setImageResource` is a better choice above `setImageDrawable`.

My guess would be that the `setImageResource` is used for lazy loading images, and `setImageDrawable` is used when you already loaded the image through a Drawable during view initiation. Which one is suiting you best probably depends on whether you have more serious memory constraints or not; in my experience, `setImageResource` is scarcely ever needed.

And to answer why your code doesn't work; this is because you can't do `getDrawable()` from a resourceId 0, [this throws an exception as it can't find the resource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29). Since `setImageResource` is lazy loading, [it checks if the resource is 0](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.setImageResource%28int%29) before creating the Drawable, and hence throws no exception.
You could probably refactor it to an `if(checked) setImageDrawable(..) else setImageDrawable(null);`

Comment: I have this .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(pickerListView.isItemChecked(position) ? R.drawable.bgpickerselected : 0)); -- this one is not working the setImageResource does

Comment: edited the answer to reflect on why your code doesn't work ;)

Comment: cool thanks. i need to conserve memory , project is running too many images

Comment: i guess when you have your images on the res/ then use setImageResource instead of setImageDrawable

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a bit difference in both the methods.

the first one, `setImageResource` is used when you have the required image in your **res** folder. But whereas the second method `setImageDrawable` is likely to be used when you create a Object of type Drawable.

Also it should be noted that, a **resource** file can be converted to a Drawable type but it is not possible to convert Drawable to Resource.

When you have your image in your res folder, it is well and good if you use the first method instead of converting it to Drawable and then using the second method.

Answer (score 0):

A drawable would be in memory setImageResource is a point to the id stored in gen files